# Rotate a matrix with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, imshow, affinetransform

I am **rotating** a n x n matrix (n = 20, although it could change) **30 degrees rightwards**  using Matplotlib's **transformation** methods.

The **error** shows up because rotation is perfomed from the top and not from the base.
I have tried to inverse the index through `np.flip()` or `ax.imshow(origin = 'lower')` but it also invert the triangle, so I need to discovered how to set the **transformation origin point**.

Defintley, this is **what I would like to obtain**:

[image: 2]

Note that the little squares that conforms the diagonal matrix would be turned into triangles. Could this be done? Maybe by an imshow method that returns half a pixel?
The rest of the pixeles would stay the same (deformed little squares).

Here is the code for generate the matrix (**starting point**):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

matrix = np.random.rand(20,20)

# Generate a boolean matrix (same shape than 'matrix') and select lower triangle values:

condition = np.tril(np.ones((matrix.shape))).astype(np.bool)
triangle = np.where(condition, matrix, np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))

ax.imshow(triangle, cmap = 'Spectral')
```

[image: 1]

And here is the **code trying to rotate** it:

```
im = ax.imshow(matrix, cmap = 'Spectral')
im.set_transform(mtransforms.Affine2D().skew(30, 0) + ax.transData)
ax.plot(transform = trans_data)
```

[image]

I am not using Triangle class of Matplotlib because the ternary diagram is represented througout an interpolation operation, and I want to represent the original matrix values.

I'd really appreciate some one's help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the origin of the skew transformation, you could chain it with a translation in the x direction to achieve the transformation you are looking for.

Note that the `skew` transform takes an angle in radians (you were using it with degrees). There is an equivalent `skew_deg` transform if you want to work in degrees, but here I just work in radians.

Note also that I think you want to have an isosceles triangle with base and height both equal to 20 (or whatever you choose N to be), the angle you want is not 30 degrees, but actually arctan(1/2) (=26.56deg).

The amount you need to translate in the x direction is `xtrans = N * np.tan(angle)`.

You can chain transforms easily in matplotlib. Here we can skew first, then translate:

```
mtransforms.Affine2D().skew(-angle, 0).translate(xtrans, 0)
```

Note that this script works for any value of N.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

N = 20
matrix = np.random.rand(N, N)

# Generate a boolean matrix (same shape than 'matrix') and select lower triangle values:

condition = np.tril(np.ones((matrix.shape))).astype(np.bool)
triangle = np.where(condition, matrix, np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))

im = ax.imshow(triangle, cmap = 'Spectral')

angle = np.arctan(1/2)
xtrans = N * np.tan(angle)
im.set_transform(mtransforms.Affine2D().skew(-angle, 0).translate(xtrans, 0) + ax.transData)

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, N + 0.5)
plt.show()
```

For N = 20
[image]

And for N = 30
[image]

Comment: Hello @tmdavison . Thank you very much for all tour time.
I do not finally understand very well what you do. Sorry, I explained myself wrong. I want to rotate the matrix into an **equilateral triangle**, not isosceles.
I am trying to change `angle` and `xtrans parameters` 

`angle = np.arctan(np.pi/3)`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally obtain an equilateral triangle scaling y-axis.Here I show the code.

Therefore, it allows **converting a matrix into an equilateral triangle**, what answer my previous question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib

bins = 50
Z = np.random.rand(bins, bins)

# Generate a boolean matrix (same shape than 'matrix') and select lower triangle values:
condition = np.tril(np.ones((Z.shape))).astype(np.bool)
Z = np.where(condition, Z, np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
im = ax.imshow(Z, cmap = 'Spectral')

# Required angles (in Rad)
alpha = np.arctan(1/2)        # 26 deg angle, in radians.
beta = np.arctan(np.pi/6)     # 30 deg angle, in radians.

# Coefficients:
xtrans = np.sin(beta) * bins
scale_y = np.cos(beta)     

# Transformation:
im.set_transform(mtransforms.Affine2D().skew      (-alpha, 0)
                                       .scale     (1,scale_y)
                                       .translate (xtrans, 0) 
                                        + ax.transData)

ax.set_ylim(bins,-5)
ax.set_xlim(-5,bins)

plt.show()
```