# Not to represent half a pixel with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Does anybody know if it's possible not to represent **half the pixels** of the diagonal matrix using `plt.imshow()`?

This is graphically expressed what I am looking for:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib

bins = 5
Z = np.random.rand(bins, bins)

# Select lower triangle values:
condition = np.tril(np.ones((Z.shape))).astype(np.bool)
Z = np.where(condition, Z, np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.imshow(Z, cmap = 'Spectral')
```

I guess this could be done by covering the image with a **mask**, but it's an option I'd rather **avoid**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Patch` object as a clipping mask in matplotlib. See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib

bins = 5
Z = np.random.rand(bins, bins)

# Select lower triangle values:
condition = np.tril(np.ones((Z.shape))).astype(np.bool)
Z = np.where(condition, Z, np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(Z, cmap = 'Spectral')

tri = matplotlib.patches.Polygon([(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)], closed=True, transform=ax.transAxes)
im.set_clip_path(tri)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Diziet Asahi
Would you know how to apply it to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591629/rotate-a-matrix-with-matplotlib)? An equilateral triangle.